# How can I activate USB debugging on my phone?

Tags: android

I found a problem with USB debugging in my phone LG V10, that option not accessible to activate.
I am serching for a solution

[image]

Comment: See [this info](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-200505/)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Please connect your Phone to PC and install all drivers required then you can enable USB Debug option.
Use this for [installing Drivers](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/)